# Trouble with horizontal dropdown nav and mouseover()

Tags: jquery, mouseover, nav, submenu

I am creating a horizontal drop down navigation, and I want the drop downs to appear when a user hovers over the parent li elements. Everything is working okay, but I am having a problem with the sub-menus appearing even if the user isn't hovering over the li elements.

Specifically, the first time a user visits the menu it acts fine, but on subsequent mouseovers the sub-menu of the last li element will appear even if the user isn't hovering on that li element, or any li element. It appears just as the user enters the header area. Here is the code, and a jsfiddle:

HTML:

```
<div id = "header">
<nav id = "main-nav-container">
  <ul id = "main-nav-menu">
    <li class = "main-nav-item">
      <a href = "#" class = "main-nav-link">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class = "main-nav-item">
      <a href = "#" class = "main-nav-link">Item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class = "main-nav-item has-sub-menu">
      <a href = "#" class = "main-nav-link">Item 3</a>
      <ul class = "sub-menu">
        <li class = "sub-menu-item">
          <a href = "#" class = "sub-menu-link">Sub 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class = "sub-menu-item">
          <a href = "#" class = "sub-menu-link">Sub 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class = "sub-menu-item">
          <a href = "#" class = "sub-menu-link">Sub 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class = "main-nav-item has-sub-menu">
      <a href = "#" class = "main-nav-link">Item 4</a>
      <ul class = "sub-menu">
        <li class = "sub-menu-item">
          <a href = "sub-menu-link">Sub 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class = "sub-menu-item">
          <a href = "sub-menu-link">Sub 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class = "sub-menu-item">
          <a href = "sub-menu-link">Sub 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class = "sub-menu-item">
          <a href = "sub-menu-link">Sub 4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color:#fff;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

a {
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
}

ul {
  list-style:none;
}

.clear:after {
  content:".";
  clear:both;
  height:0;
  visibility:hidden;
}

#header {
  width:100%;
  height:65px;
  background-color:#c11728;
  transition:height linear .2s;
}

nav {
  text-align:right;
}

#main-nav-menu {
  display:inline-block;
}

.main-nav-item {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  white-space:nowrap;
  padding:20px;
}

.sub-menu {
  display:inline-block;
  opacity:0;
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:30px;
  transition:opacity ease .2s;
  left:0;
}

.sub-menu-item {
  display:inline;
  padding:5px 20px;
}

.show-menu {
  opacity:1;
  z-index:10;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$("#main-nav-menu .main-nav-item:not(:last-child) .sub-menu").each(function() {
  var newPos = $(this).width() - 90;
  $(this).css("transform", "translateX(-" + (newPos/2) + "px)");
});

$("#main-nav-menu .main-nav-item:last-child .sub-menu").each(function() {
  var newPos = $(this).width() - 90;
  $(this).css("transform", "translateX(-" + (newPos) + "px)");
});

$(".has-sub-menu").mouseover(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation;
  $(this).children(".sub-menu").addClass("show-menu");
  var addHeight = $(this).children(".sub-menu").height();
  $("#header").css("height", ((65 + addHeight) + "px"));
}).mouseout(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation;
  var newPos = $(this).children(".sub-menu").width() - 90;
  $(this).children(".sub-menu").removeClass("show-menu");
  $("#header").css("height", (65 + "px"));
});
```

jsFiddle:

[Horizontal nav with jquery](https://jsfiddle.net/jaspercreel/n5t67j3k/117/)

I guess my question is why. Why is this happening? How come the mouseover event that is adding the show-menu class to the submenu is triggering even if the user isn't mousing over the li element attached to it? What am I not seeing? Thanks!

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me?

Comment: Hmm... try entering the menu area from the bottom, underneath the second menu item which doesn't have a submenu so it shouldn't trigger anything appearing. For me, doing that still triggers the last sub-menu.

Comment: It's something to do with the child element is there, but just not visible - so when you hover over it, the "mouseenter" is triggering. Just finishing work now so if I remember I'll sort something out later - but change it to display:none and fadeIn, rather than opacity: 0 to opacity: 1.